# What is happening behind these char array declerations?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, alias

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <string.h> //memcpy

void main(void)
{
    char* charMem = (char*) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(charMem, "Hello", 5);

    char charArr[] = "Hello";

    printf(" charMem = %p\n", charMem);
    printf("&charMem = %p\n\n", &charMem);

    printf(" charArr= %p\n", charArr);
    printf("&charArr= %p\n\n", &charArr);

    charMem[2] = 'A';
    charArr[2] = 'A';
}
```

And output is:

```
 charMem = 00F8ABB0 //diff
&charMem = 00CFFBB0 //diff

 charArr= 00CFFBA0 //same
&charArr= 00CFFBA0 //same
```

What is happening behind the compiler that leads to these results?

Comment: 1) How can the address and the value of charArr can be same?
2) Why the error occurres with a valid statement that compiles without any warning?

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha

Comment: @AndrewHenle My 2. question was a duplicate so i deleted it.

Comment: Note that after `memcpy()` your `charMem` does not point to a string because `'/0'` is not accounted for ... and that your `charArr` points to the initial char of a /*readonly*/ 6-byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare charPtr as a pointer to char and initialize it to point to a string "Hello".

The string "Hello" is kept in a read-only region of memory, so when you try to modify the 3rd location of the string "Hello" it crashes.

Correct it to declare it so

```
char charPtr[] = "Hello";
```

Declaring it like that you will be able to mutate the array charPtr[].

Looking in the annex [`J.2 Undefined behavior`](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) wee see that it is undefined when

```
— The program attempts to modify a string literal (6.4.5).
```

Answer (score 2):

> `char* charPtr = "Hello";`

`"Hello"` is a **readonly** array of `char`. Modifying its contents is undefined behaviour.

Some programmers like to help themselves with

```
const char *charPtr = "Hello";
```

so that the compiler checks for attempted changes to the readonly array contents.

```
charPtr[2] = 'A'; // attempt to change a readonly/const element
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a satisfying answer to the 2. question.